# Pine Script Zigzag Offset

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Below is default zigzag code of Pine Script. All I want is to offset (move into future).

It;s using line.new function but I am unable to make the zigzag move in future if someone could guide me. I Have added offset variable that I want to use to shift/move my zigzag with. Rest of the calculation is fine as its default I just want to have them shifted in future somehow.

```
//@version=5

dev_threshold = input.float(title='Deviation (%)', defval=5.0, minval=0.00001, maxval=100.0)
depth = input.int(title='Depth', defval=10, minval=1)
line_color = input(title='Line Color', defval=#2962FF)
extend_to_last_bar = input(title='Extend to Last Bar', defval=true)
display_reversal_price = input(title='Display Reversal Price', defval=true)
display_cumulative_volume = input(title='Display Cumulative Volume', defval=true)
display_reversal_price_change = input.bool(title='Display Reversal Price Change', defval=true, inline='price rev')
difference_price = input.string('Absolute', '', options=['Absolute', 'Percent'], inline='price rev')
offsets = input.int(100,'offset')

pivots(src, length, isHigh) =>
    p = nz(src[length])
    if length == 0
        [bar_index, p]
    else
        isFound = true
        for i = 0 to length - 1 by 1
            if isHigh and src[i] > p
                isFound := false
                isFound
            if not isHigh and src[i] < p
                isFound := false
                isFound
        for i = length + 1 to 2 * length by 1
            if isHigh and src[i] >= p
                isFound := false
                isFound
            if not isHigh and src[i] <= p
                isFound := false
                isFound
        if isFound and length * 2 <= bar_index
            [bar_index[length], p]
        else
            [int(na), float(na)]
[iH, pH] = pivots(high, math.floor(depth / 2), true)
[iL, pL] = pivots(low, math.floor(depth / 2), false)

calc_dev(base_price, price) =>
    100 * (price - base_price) / base_price

price_rotation_aggregate(price_rotation, pLast, cum_volume) =>
    str = ''
    if display_reversal_price
        str += str.tostring(pLast, format.mintick) + ' '
        str
    if display_reversal_price_change
        str += price_rotation + ' '
        str
    if display_cumulative_volume
        str += '\n' + cum_volume
        str
    str

caption(isHigh, iLast, pLast, price_rotation, cum_volume) =>
    price_rotation_str = price_rotation_aggregate(price_rotation, pLast, cum_volume)
    if display_reversal_price or display_reversal_price_change or display_cumulative_volume
        if not isHigh
            label.new(iLast, pLast, text=price_rotation_str, style=label.style_none, yloc=yloc.belowbar, textcolor=color.red)
        else
            label.new(iLast, pLast, text=price_rotation_str, style=label.style_none, yloc=yloc.abovebar, textcolor=color.green)

price_rotation_diff(pLast, price) =>
    if display_reversal_price_change
        tmp_calc = price - pLast
        str = difference_price == 'Absolute' ? (math.sign(tmp_calc) > 0 ? '+' : '') + str.tostring(tmp_calc, format.mintick) : (math.sign(tmp_calc) > 0 ? '+' : '-') + str.tostring(math.abs(tmp_calc) * 100 / pLast, format.mintick) + '%'
        str := '(' + str + ')'
        str
    else
        ''
volume_sum(index1, index2) =>
    float CVI = 0
    for i = index1 + 1 to index2 by 1
        CVI += volume[bar_index - i]
        CVI
    str.tostring(CVI, format.volume)

var line lineLast = na
var label labelLast = na
var int iLast = 0
var float pLast = 0
var bool isHighLast = true  // otherwise the last pivot is a low pivot
var int linesCount = 0

pivotFound(dev, isHigh, index, price) =>
    if isHighLast == isHigh and not na(lineLast)
        // same direction
        if isHighLast ? price > pLast : price < pLast
            if linesCount <= 1
                line.set_xy1(lineLast, index, price)
            line.set_xy2(lineLast, index, price)
            label.set_xy(labelLast, index, price)
            label.set_text(labelLast, price_rotation_aggregate(price_rotation_diff(line.get_y1(lineLast), price), price, volume_sum(line.get_x1(lineLast), index)))
            [lineLast, labelLast, isHighLast, false]
        else
            [line(na), label(na), bool(na), false]
    else
        // reverse the direction (or create the very first line)
        if na(lineLast)
            id = line.new(index, price, index, price, color=line_color, width=2)
            lb = caption(isHigh, index, price, price_rotation_diff(pLast, price), volume_sum(index, index))
            [id, lb, isHigh, true]
        else
            // price move is significant
            if math.abs(dev) >= dev_threshold
                id = line.new(iLast, pLast, index, price, color=line_color, width=2)
                lb = caption(isHigh, index, price, price_rotation_diff(pLast, price), volume_sum(iLast, index))
                [id, lb, isHigh, true]
            else
                [line(na), label(na), bool(na), false]


if not na(iH) and not na(iL) and iH == iL
    dev1 = calc_dev(pLast, pH)
    [id2, lb2, isHigh2, isNew2] = pivotFound(dev1, true, iH, pH)
    if isNew2
        linesCount += 1
        linesCount
    if not na(id2)
        lineLast := id2
        labelLast := lb2
        isHighLast := isHigh2
        iLast := iH
        pLast := pH
        pLast
    dev2 = calc_dev(pLast, pL)
    [id1, lb1, isHigh1, isNew1] = pivotFound(dev2, false, iL, pL)
    if isNew1
        linesCount += 1
        linesCount
    if not na(id1)
        lineLast := id1
        labelLast := lb1
        isHighLast := isHigh1
        iLast := iL
        pLast := pL
        pLast
else
    if not na(iH)
        dev1 = calc_dev(pLast, pH)
        [id, lb, isHigh, isNew] = pivotFound(dev1, true, iH, pH)
        if isNew
            linesCount += 1
            linesCount
        if not na(id)
            lineLast := id
            labelLast := lb
            isHighLast := isHigh
            iLast := iH
            pLast := pH
            pLast
    else
        if not na(iL)
            dev2 = calc_dev(pLast, pL)
            [id, lb, isHigh, isNew] = pivotFound(dev2, false, iL, pL)
            if isNew
                linesCount += 1
                linesCount
            if not na(id)
                lineLast := id
                labelLast := lb
                isHighLast := isHigh
                iLast := iL
                pLast := pL
                pLast

var line extend_line = na
var label extend_label = na
if extend_to_last_bar == true and barstate.islast == true
    isHighLastPoint = not isHighLast
    curSeries = isHighLastPoint ? high : low
    if na(extend_line) and na(extend_label)
        extend_line := line.new(line.get_x2(lineLast), line.get_y2(lineLast), bar_index, curSeries, color=line_color, width=2)
        extend_label := caption(not isHighLast, bar_index, curSeries, price_rotation_diff(line.get_y2(lineLast), curSeries), volume_sum(line.get_x2(lineLast), bar_index))
        extend_label

    line.set_xy1(extend_line, line.get_x2(lineLast), line.get_y2(lineLast))
    line.set_xy2(extend_line, bar_index, curSeries)
    label.set_xy(extend_label, bar_index, curSeries)
    price_rotation = price_rotation_diff(line.get_y1(extend_line), curSeries)
    volume_cum = volume_sum(line.get_x1(extend_line), bar_index)
    label.set_text(extend_label, price_rotation_aggregate(price_rotation, curSeries, volume_cum))
    label.set_textcolor(extend_label, isHighLastPoint ? color.green : color.red)
    label.set_yloc(extend_label, yloc=isHighLastPoint ? yloc.abovebar : yloc.belowbar)
```